# ASP MVC 3 validate field when field lose focus even if it was not changed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am testing mvc field validation. For this I did a new ASP MVC 3 project in VS2010. I selected razor view engine for it. The default project generates me a home account controllers and a logon action.

In the LogOn view I want to validate fields when field looses focus. If I go on username and I press tab without changing the field the validation does not trigger.

Is this the normal behavior? ... or I miss something. 
If this is the normal behavior ... how can I validate field after it loses focus even if it was not changed.

I did not changed anything at the application template that vs generate for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using jquery 1.7.1 with unobtrusive validation, something like this should do the trick:

```
<script>
    $('input[data-val=true]').on('blur', function() {
        $(this).valid();
    });
</script>
```

If using an older version of jquery, change to this:

```
<script>
    $('input[data-val=true]').blur(function() {
        $(this).valid();
    });
</script>
```